# applidium/HeaderListView not working correct

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement [applidium/HeaderListView](https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView) and having still troubles. It worked - nothing changed and now it doesn't work anymore...

I have 4 sections and CheckedTextViews as row contents...
I succeeded in preventing `NullPointerException`s, but after scrolling the list goes crazy...

Here my 2 adapter methods:

```
@Override
public View getRowView(final int section, final int row, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    boolean firstTime = convertView == null;
    Item item = getItem(section, row);

    if (firstTime) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.character_list_item, new ListView(context), false);
    }
    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_character);
    if (checkedTextView != null) {
        if (firstTime) // only one click listener needed
            checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onClickListener(v, section, row);
                }
            });
        checkedTextView.setText(item.getText());
        loadSettings(checkedTextView, section, row); // recovers checked state
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getSectionHeaderView(final int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.character_header, new ListView(context), false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listheader_character);
    if (textView != null) textView.setText(getHeaders().get(section).getText());
    return convertView;
}
```

I tried to do it like the online example, but it didn't work.

Has anybody a idea to finally fix it?

The list entries are currently fine, but the headers are <s>not always showing</s> showing multiple times after scrolling and the first one is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

searched for other libraries and recyclerview solutions and got it to work with: [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)